# Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')) when testing python model

Tags: python, json, post

I'm building a machine learning predictive model. I'm trying to test my predict.py which should be located at http://localhost:9696/predict. When I use Jupyter Notebook to test it out, I get this error message "Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')) when testing python model"

I'm 99% sure that's the correct URL because I have a ping.py file that I can access by putting localhost:9696/ping into the address bar (its method is GET rather than POST, so I won't be able to access predict.py through the address bar). Could a setting on my computer be blocking it?

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry


session = requests.Session()
retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount('http://', adapter)
session.mount('https://', adapter)

url='http://localhost:9696/predict'
session.get(url)
```

Comment: Your Jupiter notebook server is definitely running on the same machine as your "predictive model" server? If not, or if jupyter is in a container or something, localhost could be a different network interface than you're hitting with your browser.

Comment: Yup, I was using juptyer notebook on the same machine. Oddly enough, I rebooted and relaunched everything and it worked. It's super odd, I've never had this happen before.